# Speed up Sesame load of rdf files

Tags: rdf, sesame

Is there any way to speed up the load of rdf files into Sesame? I have files ranging in size from a few of MB to a couple of GB in N-triple format. I have tried the three first approaches in [Sesame Cook Book](http://rivuli-development.com/further-reading/sesame-cookbook/loading-large-file-in-sesame-native/), but to no avail. I loaded a ~700MB file in 17 hours by splitting the input file at every 500,000th line (approach 2 in the [cook book](http://rivuli-development.com/further-reading/sesame-cookbook/loading-large-file-in-sesame-native/)). Sesame is running on a commodity machine with Windows 7.

Bonus part: I want to perform inference on the data, but store the inferred data in a separate sesame repository (or alternatively in another context/graph in the same repository). Essentially I want to store the data in two versions, one which is "regular" rdf and one which is optimized for certain queries - hence the need for storing them separately. I have been looking at the [CustomGraphQueryInferencer](http://openrdf.callimachus.net/sesame/2.7/apidocs/org/openrdf/sail/inferencer/fc/CustomGraphQueryInferencer.html), but have not figured out if I can use this to store the data separately. Furthermore, the [CustomGraphQueryInferencer](http://openrdf.callimachus.net/sesame/2.7/apidocs/org/openrdf/sail/inferencer/fc/CustomGraphQueryInferencer.html) seems to slow down the load time greatly, thus making it very unattractive. Any alternative solutions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inserting 500k triples in 17 hours is **absurdly** bad; that's about 8 triples/sec.  Sesame, to my knowledge, does not have a bulk insert mode, but there's no way you should be seeing load rates which are *that* slow.

You might make sure you don't have autoCommit on; that'd be doing commits for each triple, which could go a long way toward explaining why your load rate is so uncommonly poor.

With respect to reasoning, another factor for the poor load rate is that you are using an inferencer that performs materialization.  That is, each time you write to the database, inferred statements are (re)calculated and saved back into the database.  Further, the inferencer you've chosen to use is based on queries, so your loads into the database are hampered by query answering, truth maintenance, and materialization.

That is probably a large part of the poor load rate, although, it still seems even too slow for that.  But perhaps combined with autoCommit being enabled, that might explain it.

You might be able to add the inferencer after all the data is loaded, I don't know enough about how that particular inferencer works to know if that is correct, but in theory, it's certainly possible.  The Sesame mailing list might have more details about how it works.

You can also consider a solution which performs reasoning at query time rather than load time; this does not have the costly overhead for writes, and also allows you to use, or not use, reasoning whenever is most appropriate for your application.  That'd effectively let you have your two 'versions' of the data, one with reasoning applied and one without, without actually having to have two versions or materialize the inferences.

Comment: I'm not sure the load rate is actually that bad, the OP states he split the raw file into 500k chunks but he doesn't say how many chunks he had.  The 17 hours appears to be for loading all the chunks

Comment: I have made a java jar file, which loads a dataset, with all dependencies included and tried running it on my own Linux laptop I get about 10000-20000 triples/sec depending on varisous options. When I transfer the jar and dataset file to the Windows computer (which is more powerful in CPU and RAM, disks are probably similar) I only get around 50-100 triples/sec. The source code is at: https://github.com/kimajakobsen/sesame-repository-test-workspace

Comment: Disabling autocommit sped up the initial triples (first 10k in ~1s), but then its downhill from there (next 10k in 55s). Running as: java -jar sesam-1.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar --load --chunk 10k tmp customer.ttl

Comment: I may add a correction: The 17 hours was for an entire dataset, i.e. 10 files of ~70MB each containing 500,000 triples (except for the last one which had slightly less) to a total of 4.8 millions, which means the avg. load time is 78 triples/sec, which is still very slow.

Comment: If you're running java w/o setting memory, you very probably are seeing gc overhead affect the results.  10k as a chunk size is too small.  Forward chaining inference is expensive during writes, no matter what.

Comment: It does not commit every 10k triple(in the above example), only write some output to the terminal.

Comment: Which SAILs can run inference on query time? The standard SAILs (RDFS, CustomGraph, and DirectTypeHierarchy) are all used at load time as far as I could gather and I assumed that was an established standard. Ideally I want both to be able to measure the tradeoff between load and query time using materialized inference vs query time inference.

Comment: if you're not committing regularly, you're definitely hitting GC issues in addition to the work of inferencing and loading.  You are probably measuring your code more than you're measuring sesame.  No sesame sail does query time reasoning that i'm aware of; you'd need a sesame-compatible, 3rd party solution if you want query time reasoning.